# Vue.js 2.5 list rendering

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array in JS/Vue that I would like to display in `<ul>`/`<li>` tags, and keep updated as the array gets new elements.

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulist">
    <li v-for="user in users">
        @{{ user }} <!-- "@" needed since this is in a laravel project with blade templates -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var socket = io('localhost:3000');

  new Vue({
     el: "#ulist",

     data: {
            users: []
           },

     mounted: function() {
        this.$nextTick(function() {
           socket.on('test-action', function(data) {
              this.users.push(data.username);
              console.log(data.username);
           }.bind(this));
        });
     }
  });
</script>
```

The array is being properly populated (as I can see via the console.log statement), but the `<li v-for="user in users">...` part doesn't seem to be working as none of the `<li>...</li>` elements get created. What am I doing wrong here?

Just to clarify: if I add hard coded values to the users array, those values show up in `<li>` elements fine, but no additional values that are added to the array (in the `mounted` function) show up in `<li>...</li>` elements.

Edit: version is 2.5.13, if it matters

Comment: when dealing with array changes you sometimes have to use set the values like this:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 2):

**Can you try this ?**

```
<script>
    var socket = io('localhost:3000');

    new Vue({
        el: "#ulist",

        data: {
            users: []
        },

        mounted: function() {
            var _self = this;
            this.$nextTick(function() {
                socket.on('test-action', function(data) {
                    self.users.push(data.username);
                    console.log(data.username);
                }.bind(this));
            });
        }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: is `_self` and `self` are same ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't seem to make a difference for me. I always thought using `_self = this;` was an alternative (in some situations) to `.bind(this)`. Is that right? I didn't think both would be needed like you have in your example

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the scope of your `this` variable. In your code this line:

```
this.users.push(data.username);
```

is scoped to the function call within the ajax request, if you use `() =>` it will keep the current scope in context within your method. Also, you shouldn't need `nextTick` within the mounted call so try this:

```
<script>
    var socket = io('localhost:3000');

    new Vue({
        el: "#ulist",

        data: {
            users: []
        },

        mounted: function() {
            socket.on('test-action', data => {
                this.users.push(data.username);
                console.log(data.username);
            });
        }
    });
 </script>
```

Although you were using `bind(this)` you were using `this` within `nextTick` which was causing scope issues.

Another thing worth noting, lists require a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) in vue v?? (I can't remember which) so it's best to add a key when using `v-for`:

```
<ul id="ulist">
    <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
        @{{ user }} <!-- "@" needed since this is in a laravel project with blade templates -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the arrow function syntax I don't think I can use `.bind(this)` anymore. Is that correct? I tried using this example but it results in a syntax error unless the `bind` call is removed.

Comment: Apologies, that was a mistake on my part. Just remove the bind and it should all work out well. I've updated my code to suit.